# Story about a man bringing nanomachines from the future to save his lover

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, nanotechnology

Many years ago I read a short (?) sci-fi story that I've since lost track of.

Here's what I remember:

1. A man came from the future, met a girl, fell in love, told her he was from the future and (not so sure about this part) found out that she was dying and left her a pill/shot of nanomachines to save her from her illness
2. The girl lived in a remote part of the United States (?), in a very distinct rural area with mountains and trees that meant a lot to her.
3. Said man then went back to the future (?), Humanity gained access to nanomachines, became immortal and started exploring the Universe. The girl/woman was one of the the first explorers and visited many planets
4. She came back from her exploration, back to the place where she was born to wander amongst the tress/mountains she grew up with
5. The nanomachines were injected in the brain stem

Sorry in advance if the details are a bit fuzzy but it was many years ago. Scoured Google but was unable to find anything (likely on the account of misremembering some/most of the details).

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: @Edlothiad thank you, I'll try to remember some more details and make I'm remembering the details in the question right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like it could be [The Gentle Seduction](http://www.skyhunter.com/marcs/GentleSeduction.html) by [Marc Stiegler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Stiegler).

It has Nano-technology that heal people's ailments:

> She started to climb the Mountain, but it was too much for her: she huffed and puffed and had to go home. Annoyed, she went to the drug store and bought another capsule, **one that restored her circulatory system and her lungs**.
>
> One day as she skied across the slopes, a stranger passed her going the other way. He was tall and rugged, and he reminded her of her husband. She was annoyed that he did not even look at her, though she had smiled at him; when she looked in the mirror upon returning home, she understood why. She was 95 years old; she looked like an old woman. It was ridiculous; **fortunately it was easily fixed**.
>
> When she turned 115 she stabilized her physical appearance. Thereafter, she **always appeared to be about the age of 32**.

Humanity is able to explore the Solar System:

> She talked to her children, and her children's children, more often now; though they were spread from **Mars to Mercury**, they were but a thought away.
>
> The discussion turned to the family's upcoming **expedition to Jupiter**.

And at the end she returns to Earth to hike the mountain she used to hike with her lover

> The day came to say goodbye to her oldest friend. With her wonderful old earth-born body, she returned to Earth to hike Rainier one last time: Rainier, whose surface lay so cold and eternal, was boiling within.

Comment: That's the story I thought of when I read the question. However, I don't remember any time-travel in "The Gentle Seduction". There isn't any, is there? I wonder if the OP could be mixing up two different stories?

Comment: Yes, that's it!! Thank you very much. Footnote: `Meanwhile humanity was failing. The anticipation, the yearning, the hope for contact with new beings developed a tinge of desperation.` that's why I kept thinking about the Crystal Spheres.

Comment: @user14111 very likely, I apologize if I got the time travel bit wrong (as you can read from my comment above, I tend to weave stories together).